# What are the exact orthography, etymology and explicit semantics of галимо/голимо?

Tags: этимология, орфография, semantics, социолингвистика

In phrases like:

> Это г@лимый бред.
>
> Это г@лимыe сопли.

The word has been detected in conversational register of middle/low class native speakers in NW Russia, sometimes in fictional literature to convey such a register. It is pronounced with the stressed ***и***.

The overall meaning is perhaps 'sheer', 'mere' or 'that of a worst kind', or all the three aspects together. But what are the exact semantics?

Can it be a borrowing from one of Gipsy languages in Russia (I am not sure from which one of them) where the word *галима* (pronounced with stress on final a) means 'bad'?

Comment: Will you please give a prooflink to the fact that in one of Gipsy languages in Russia there is the word галима which means 'bad'. If there is such a word, did you consider the possibility that it's a borowing from Russian?

Comment: I had a field research on that some years ago, but lost my interest. I think there is no such a link, and I doubt if it is a borrowing from Russian, since the Yer is stressed. Therefore it could not change into Ee by any phonemic rules.

Comment: I changed the title back so that it would be googlable.

Comment: OK. I changed the text so it would convey the meaning intended.

Comment: Still, there's no proof the word exists in the Gipsy language.

Comment: There is no proof for its non-existance in a Romani language either.

Comment: No Gipsy dictionary I know of has this word.

Comment: Try some field research then.

Comment: Adjectives in the Gipsy language cannot end in -a. And yes, I did some field research on the issue.

Comment: There are several Romani languages. Which one did yoy exactly have made your field research on?

Comment: There's one Romani language, I have made my field research on several dialects thereof. I don't know about any variation of Romani that has adjectives ending in -a, they end in -o, -i, or a consonant. The point is, you cannot prove what you write here, there's no Romani dictionary or grammar that lists that "галима". I can also say I know a guy who uses the Russian word "гагн" that means "sister" and ask you about its possible eymology. Dictionaries don't have that word, but I heard it myself, believe it or not.

Comment: There is more than one Romani language. The question is about Russian, not Romany word. Please do some study on language:dialect problemme before continuing this discussion.

Comment: Thank you, I don't need to do any study of that, I did it, that's why I've been teaching that to my students. You are too generous in advising others what they should do, why don't you do a study of some kind, rather than being fastuous towards those who want to help you and answer your questions?

Comment: Do you teach Romani languages? Or do you teach linguistics?

Comment: What I teach includes _language:dialect problemme_ as a part of it. I greatly doubt Romani is taught somewhere in the CIS or Baltia, that would be a great joy for me to find out I'm wrong about Romani being taught.

Answer (score 2):

Since the adjective/adverb is now generally perceived as a derogatory one, I assume, the following excerpt from Vladimir Dahl's dictionary entry(aka Explanatory Dictionary of the Live Great Russian language)I have stumbled upon recently, might prove relevant here or possibly shed some light on its quite obscure origin:

ГАЛИТЬ вят. гадовать, блевать, рвать, тошнить, тянуть с души. Его галить. Более говор. о грудных младенцах. Галить или галеть или галить сев. галегать зап. галяндать сев. олон. шалить, проказить, дурить, шутить, смешить: или зубоскалить, смеяться. || Арх. лягаться? || Галить сиб. подавать мяч или шар в игре, гилить. Галиться над кем, сев. изгаляться, смеяться, насмехаться, издеваться. || Новг. пск. ниж. орл. пялить глаза, глазеть, смотреть, дивиться или любоваться, засматриваться. На красавицу люди галятся. || Галить младенца, орл. дать полежать несвитому; он галится, тянется и подает голос. Галенье ср. новг. яросл. перм. смех, насмешка, насмешничество. То–то будет галенья! Галяй, пск. кто галится, насмешник.

Supposedly, the verbal definitions particularly related to those of various "vomit" derivatives and especially marked by the vulgar register such as "throw up" and/or "puke" as well as cat, retch, barf, spew, spue, might potentially approximate to "галить, гадовать, блевать", etc. if not in totally overlapped meaning but at least on a highly pejorative scale. 
  At some point the verb "галить", having its origin from the country's rural areas and, consequently, of a regional, dialectal tinge, might have transformed into the adjective "галимый"(hypothetically, retaining the same root)that ended up proliferating among urban lower class communities with poor educational background in the course of influx into big cities.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably derived from `галиматья` (from `galimatias` «неразбериха», Parisian students' slang).

Also, there are no *Gipsy languages*, all the Romani people speak the same language with lots of local dialects.

Comment: That depends mainly on what you consider to be a language and what you consider to be a dialect (no, I didn't downvote :-)

Comment: @ Manjusri - It's not just me, most linguists also think so. Besides, the differences between those dialects are too little for them to be considered distinct languages.

Comment: I doubt Russian Kelderari speaker would understand e.g. Lauise Romani.

Comment: @ Manjusri - Why do you think so?

Comment: The grammars are different.

Comment: @Manjusri - Laiuse Romani is Gipsy mixed with Estonian, that's a mixed language, not Gipsy proper.

Comment: That gets back to a discussion on what is a language and what is a dialect. By the way, I have said 'languages'.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a borrowing from one of Gipsy languages (you are not sure which one of them).

[According](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9) to Phasmer:

> Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли:
>   ст.-слав. голъ (др.-греч. γυμνός), руск. голый, укр. го́лий, белор.
>   го́лы, болг. гол, сербохорв. го̑, го̀ла, го̀ло, словенск. gòl, góla,
>   чешск. holý, польск. goły, в.-луж. hoły, н.-луж. goły. Родственно
>   латышск. gāla «гололедица», gàle ж. «тонкая корка льда», др.-в.-нем.
>   kalo «лысый». Сюда же (с другим вокализмом) польск. gałąź, чешск.
>   haluz «ветвь».

Original form was `голимый`, but due to the process of shifting from `о` to `а` in Russian dialect which finally became major one, form `галимый` had been introduced. This is the same reason why forms гондон/гандон (о-form is correct) and изгаляться/изголяться (a-form is correct) coexist.

This word is known at least [from XVIII century](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/04/sl515208.htm) (already with negative connotations) and, I repeat, definitely has nothing in common with any Romani dialect lexeme.

In it first sense `голимый` meant something pure, so it related to `беспримесный`, `чистый`, `незамутнённый`. So `галимый бред` is basically `pure nonsense`.

There's related word `голяк``полный голяк` which is used to describe the state of catastrophic lack of something, money for example.

Comment: This results in three questions. First, why the -м- suffix is used? Second, what is the oldest written attestation of this word in Russian? Third, is it/has it ever been used in modern Russian in positive sense?

Comment: по аналогии с любовь/любимый - суффикс не -им-, а не -м-, в современном русском ни в каком контексте это слово положительной коннотации не несёт, что касается второго вашего подвопроса, то это вопрос на который вам вряд ли кто-то даст ответ точнее века)

Comment: Если слово появилось не раньше конца девятнадцатого-начала двадцатого, то велика вероятность заимствования из цыганских языков. Суффикс, каким бы он ни был, достаточно интересен и заслуживает отдельного вопроса.

Comment: довольно типичный для русского словооброзования суффикс и нет, слово появилось гораздо раньше 19-го века.

Comment: Could you give any proof to your claims pls?

Comment: @Manjusri yes, sir, I can indeed ))) http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/04/sl515208.htm

Comment: downvoters, please, explain

Comment: That's an interesting resourse, but how can you explain the switch from Yer to Ee-letter? And how does the Vasmer's version corresponds to the Yer in general?

Comment: Had you down voted my answer? I yes, please, explain why.

Comment: No, I have not. I have upvoted it, actually.

Comment: @Manjusri, it is actually interesting indeed. Switch from yat to и is not typical for Russian though perfectly imaginable, since it is exactly what happened in Ukrainian, for example.

Comment: In stressed positions?

Comment: @shabunc: not my downvote, but could you please link to the dictionary itself and not to wiktionary? I can find this word neither in my printed edition nor online.

Comment: @shabunc: relax, they are just fascists

Comment: @Manjusri: who are fascists?

Comment: @Manjusri - `Ѣ` is not 'Yer', that is `ять`.

Comment: @Yellow Sky: whatever. My point was that it was a sound which  has historically been  nasalised.

Comment: `ѣ`, `ъ` and `ь` were never nasalised. Irrespective of whether its position was stressed or not, `ѣ` changed into modern Russian `e` everywhere. What you've been writing makes me think you need some rest today.